# TypeScript return conditional type from factory function

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have a union type of objects that can under certain conditions be assigned a special behavior. This behavior depends on the type of object. Some of the objects are more special than others and can have more or different functions.

I want to create a factory function that takes an instance of one item of this union type and returns the right behavior class for this instance. It would look like this:

```js
type A = {
  type: "A"
  name: string,
}
type B = {
  type: "B",
  name: string,
  age: number
}

type Things = A | B


type Base<T extends Things> = {
  f1(): string
}

type Special<T extends Things> = T extends B ? { f2(): number } : {}

type Behavior<T extends Things> = Base<T> & Special<T>


class BehaviorClassA implements Behavior<A> {
  constructor(private readonly instance: A) { }
  f1(): string {
    return "some A behavior for " + this.instance.name
  }
}

class BehaviorClassB implements Behavior<B> {
  constructor(private readonly instance: B) { }
  f1(): string {
    return "some B behavior for " + this.instance.name
  }
  f2(): number {
    return this.instance.age + 42
  }
}


function getBehaviorForThing<T extends Things>(thing: T): T extends B ? BehaviorClassB : BehaviorClassA {
  if (isA(thing)) {
    return new BehaviorClassA(thing) // Type 'BehaviorClassA' is not assignable to type 'T extends B ? BehaviorClassB : BehaviorClassA'.

  }
  if (isB(thing)) {
    return new BehaviorClassB(thing) // Type 'BehaviorClassB' is not assignable to type 'T extends B ? BehaviorClassB : BehaviorClassA'.
  }
  throw new Error("invalid thing")
}

function isA(t: Things): t is A {
  return t.type === "A"
}
function isB(t: Things): t is B {
  return t.type === "B"
}


// consumer:
const myB: B = { 
  type: "B",
  name: "John",
  age: 23
}
getBehaviorForThing(myB).f2()
```

However as you can see the factory function can not be typed correctly.

Does anyone have an idea what I would have to do to get it work as intended?

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912.  This is a limitation of generic conditional types.  The only fixes right now are essentially unsafe type assertions.  It's possible that TS4.6 will let you refactor into something that compiles safely without assertions, but it won't be a simple refactor.  Let me know if you want me to write up an answer.

Comment: Thanks all. I think the function overload solution works for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

Function overload is a correct option, but you can do the followinf as well which is a "kind of" type guard:

```
type ReturnType<T> = T extends B? BehaviorClassB : BehaviorClassA
  
  function getBehaviorForThing<T extends Things>(thing: T): ReturnType<T> {
    if (isA(thing)) {
        const resu: BehaviorClassA = new BehaviorClassA(thing) 
      return resu  as ReturnType<T>
  
    }
    if (isB(thing)) {
      return new BehaviorClassB(thing) as ReturnType<T> 
    }
    throw new Error("invalid thing")
  }

 // consumer:
  const myB: B = { 
    type: "B",
    name: "John",
    age: 23
  }
  getBehaviorForThing(myB).f2() <-- is type BehaviorClassB
```